# Upgrading to Python 2.7 Google App Engine 500 server error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, server-error

I just started using Google App Engine and I am very new to Python. I may have made a stupid mistake or a fatal error, I don't know, but I realized that the basic "template" I downloaded from a website was old and used Python 2.5.

So, I decided to update to Python 2.7 (after recieving a warning in the site's dashboard).

I have no idea how to do this, but I blindly followed some instructions on how to update but I'm not sure what I did wrong.

I know that I downloaded Python 2.7 (as the download path is `C:/Python27/`), so there shouldn't be a problem there. Can anybody tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You'll have to find a way to see the error message. Server error is not it. Specify a logfile and turn on debugging.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver

Comment: You'll probably find something revealing if you go to the admin console page for this this app and look at the logs.

Comment: don't forget GAE uses it's "own" version of python, so what you are using locally should not matter once deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your respective answers and comments, but I recently stumbled upon GAE boilerplate and decided to use that and everything's fine. I kept having very odd problems with GAE beforehand, but the boilerplate is simple and seems to be working fine so far. Anyways, thanks again. (Note: I would delete the question but two people have already answered and received rep from +1s, and they are in fact helpful answers, so I'll leave it be).

Answer (score 2):

I'm submitting as an answer because I'm relatively new to SO and don't have enough rep to comment, so sorry about that... But line 7 of your new main.py uses `webapp` instead of `webapp2`, so that may be causing some troubles, but likely isn't the reason that it's not working. Could you also provide the `contact.html` template?

Comment: Ah thanks for that. And yes I will provide the contact.html stuff. It's just a skeleton of the pages with a simple contact form. Anyways, I'll edit my question now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is your formatting when you loaded your code here, but where you define `app` in main.py should not be part of the `contacts` class. If it is, your reference to `main.app` in your app.yaml won't work and your page won't load.